# Need to replace the element by the max of the right side elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to replace every element in an `array` with the max element that belong to the right side set of elements in that array. I got a solution with the below code:

```
let arr1 = [5,0,5,7,9,4,8];
var temp = [];

for (var i = 1; i < arr1.length + 1; i++)
{
    if (i !== arr1.length)
    {
        temp = [...arr1].slice(i);
        arr1[i-1] = Math.max(...temp);
    }
    else
    {
        arr1[i-1] = arr1[arr1.length - 1];
    } 
}

console.log(arr1);
```

Is there any other better solution for solve this? You can see expected output on next sample:

```
Input : [5,0,5,7,9,4,8]
Output: [9,9,9,9,8,8,8]
```

Comment: why is the value for `9` `8`, if for `8` you have `8`?

Comment: @NinaScholz for `9`, the set of elements on the right is `[4, 8]` so it is replaced by the maximum of they, `8` in this case. While for `8` (the last element) there aren't elements on the right, so is not replaced. I believe, that is the logic behind that, at least it is what I have understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve performance to *O(n)* (since your current implementation is *O(n^2)*) by iterating backwards and keeping track of the max:

```js
var arr1 = [5, 0, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8];
var max = arr1[arr1.length - 1];

for (var i = arr1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var curr = arr1[i];
  arr1[i] = max;
  if (curr > max) max = curr;
}

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Note this approach, also, do not mutates your original array.

```js
let arr1 = [5,0,5,7,9,4,8];

let res = arr1.map(
    (n, idx, arr) => (idx < arr.length-1) ? Math.max(...arr.slice(idx+1)) : n
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Another alternative with `O(n)` performance can be approached using [Array.reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight)

```js
let arr1 = [5,0,5,7,9,4,8];
let max = arr1[arr1.length - 1];

let res = arr1.reduceRight(
    (acc, n, idx) => (acc[idx] = max, max = Math.max(n, max), acc),
    []
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```